# how can I make slideshow images scale proportionately at different viewport sizes?

Tags: html, css, slideshow, scaling

I found code for a slideshow of images that I really like but that didn’t resize at different browser sizes.  I tried using the vh property to make that happen but it didn’t work – I couldn’t get the images to scale proportionately.  So I tried adding the properties max-width: 100% and height: auto which makes images scale proportionately.  But the following occurs:

1. Only the widest image will scale proportionately at all points when resizing the browser window as you make it smaller; the others will remain static until the point where the browser window is equal to the image’s width as defined by the indicated width and height properties.
2. Images center in the resized browser window as long as it is 1732 px wide (the width of the widest image and of the “stage” id which contains the images) or greater.

Is there a way to make all of the images scale smaller at all browser sizes?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

  #stage {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 1732px;
    height: 1080px;
    }

  #stage img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

  #stage img {
    padding: 10px;
    border: ;
    background: #fff;
  }

  #stage img:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-name: fader;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  #stage img:nth-of-type(2) {
    z-index: 10;
  }

  #stage img:nth-of-type(n+3) {
    display: none;
  }

  @keyframes fader {
    from { opacity: 1.0; }
    to   { opacity: 0.0; }
  }


    </style>
    </head>
<div id="stage">
<img src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/cf_spring_&_thompson_east_v_1080.jpg" width="1394" height="1080">
<img src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/cf_suffolk_btw_rivington_&_stanton_v_1080.jpg" width="1732" height="1080">
<img src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/dr_chrystie_93_v_1080.jpg" width="1165" height="1080">
<img src="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/cf_franklin_&_w_bway_v_1080.jpg" width="726" height="1080">
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  // Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
  // Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

    var maxW = 0;
    var maxH = 0;

    var stage = document.getElementById("stage");
    var fadeComplete = function(e) { stage.appendChild(arr[0]); };
    var arr = stage.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].width > maxW) maxW = arr[i].width;
      if(arr[i].height > maxH) maxH = arr[i].height;
    }
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].width < maxW) {
        arr[i].style.paddingLeft = 10 + (maxW - arr[i].width)/2 + "px";
        arr[i].style.paddingRight = 10 + (maxW - arr[i].width)/2 + "px";
      }
      if(arr[i].height < maxH) {
        arr[i].style.paddingTop = 10 + (maxH - arr[i].height)/2 + "px";
        arr[i].style.paddingBottom = 10 + (maxH - arr[i].height)/2 + "px";
      }
      arr[i].addEventListener("animationend", fadeComplete, false);
    }

  }, false);

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: So you want to make the height percent of width or what?

Comment: Presently when viewed on a screen size that exceeds the dimensions of the widest image (I am looking at the slideshow on a 27" monitor and on a 15" laptop) the images are proportionately correct.  I want them to be proportionately correct when viewed on smaller devices regardless of the size of the viewport for those devices down to approximately 720 px.

Answer (score 0):

Just add max-width to `#stage`

```
#stage{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

and put `!important` to images `max-width`

```
#stage img {
    max-width: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that adding what you noted per the code below.  Do I have this right because it didn't make a change in the slideshow.  The images still only scale once the browser window is as small as their width.  #stage {
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: 1732px;
    height: 1080px;
    max-width: 100%;
 }

  #stage img {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
    max-width: 100% !important
 }